# Reducing max audio volume without reducing base volume

Tags: linux, audio

Is there a way to reduce the maximum possible audio volume without affecting audio that is below that maximum volume? I don't care if audio that would have gone above sounds horrible and distorted as long as it never gets above the set maximum.

One usage example would be videos, podcasts or streamed content where people are talking but once in a while there are sudden loud noises. A compressor (as far as I understand how those work) wouldn't help much if it takes a while to realize that the sound's too loud. By the time it would kick in it'd be too late.

I am aware that cutting off the tops and bottoms of soundwaves with too high amplitudes sounds horrible, but it would be noise anyways, so I don't care how bad that sudden noise sounds as long as it doesn't go beyond that maximum volume no matter how fast it is.

Just to be sure we're talking about the same thing: I'm not talking about the production of such videos, podcasts etc. but about listening to them.

I'm using Archlinux/manjaro.

Answer (score 0):

You could load a LADSPA filter to your [ALSA setup](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=99185) or [PulseAudio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43950/how-can-i-apply-a-ladspa-plugin-to-a-pulseaudio-stream), it sounds like the [fastLookaheadLimiter](http://plugin.org.uk/ladspa-swh/docs/ladspa-swh.html#tth_sEc2.39) fits the description.

Comment: Hm. I don't really care about distortion, so no delay would be even better (would that be the Hard Limiter?), but if I went with one of those LADSPA filters, how would I go about integrating them into my ALSA? I think I understand the links you provided, but not the controls/options.

For the hard limiter I had to read up on what wet level and residue level are, but now that I know that, it seems to me it's missing a parameter (the limit itself). For the option you proposed, I don't know what the Attenuation parameter does, nor what to use for the other parameters (0 & guess for the first 2?)